# minimal primes generator in C

Tags: c

I have to find all the minimal primes that have at least two digits. A minimal prime is a prime number which subsequences are not primes. In order to correctly complete the exercise I cannot use arrays (they are prohibited) and I must `#define` the `maxnumb`. The problem I have here is that I cannot print the min. What I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100

int IsPrime(int number);

int main (void) {
int i,j,x,k,mask,max=1,mult,sub,c,number;
    for (i = 11 ; i < MAXNUMB; i += 2 ){
     number=IsPrime(i);
     if (number==1) {

        int length = 0;
        int tmp=i;
       while (tmp != 0) {
              tmp /= 10;
              length++;
            }

        for (x=1;x<length*2;x++) {
            mask=x;
            mult=1;
            sub=0;
            int num=i;
            int counter=0;
                while(num!=0) {
                  if ( mask % 2 == 1 ) {
                      sub += num % 10 * mult;
                      mult *= 10; 
                   }

                   num /= 10;
                   mask /= 2;
                }
                while (sub!=i){


                   int min=i;
                   k=IsPrime(sub);

                   if(k==1) 

                   counter+=1;
                   printf("%d sub \n",sub);
                   printf("%d count \n",counter);
                   break;
                   if(counter==0)
                   printf(" minimal \n",min);
               }
       }    
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
int IsPrime(int i) {
   int j;
   if (i==1)
   return 0;
   for (j=2; j*j<=i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0)
           return 0;
    }
    if (j*j>i )
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you give few examples of minimal primes.. And explain about them more clearly

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a `break` statement above the line in question, so it never gets executed.

```
printf("%d sub \n",sub);
printf("%d count \n",counter);
break;                              // <<-- remove this line
if(counter==0)
    printf(" minimal \n",min);
```

An additional problem is you don't print any value, change to this

```
if(counter==0)
    printf("%d minimal \n",min);    // add format specifier
```

Comment: but i remove break i have an infinity lopp

Comment: So move the `break` further down, or rethink the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not telling it to print `min`.
Change this line:

```
printf(" minimal \n",min);
```

To this:

```
printf("%d minimal \n",min);
```

To achieve what I think you were trying to do.

`printf` prints variables using [format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). It would be worth reading a few tutorials on how to use them :).

Answer (score 0):

I can also see an infinite loop at `while (sub!=i)` since sub doesn't change inside the loop.
To further test me add a `printf("Problematic loop")` inside the loop and see it yourself how many times it will print the statement without printing a number.